# center element to parent and allow clipping without absolute positioning

Tags: css, position, overflow, center, clip

I keep struggling with this one. I need to center a child within it's parent and if it's width exceeds that of the parent, allow the parent to clip it. This is easily done with `position: absolute;`, but the width of this element is unknown, so it's a no go.

The crafty method is setting the child to `display: inline-block;` and parent to `text-align: center;`, but this doesn't allow the clipping that I'm looking for. Instead, it aligns the child left and clips the right side. I need it to clip evenly.

Am I missing a trick or should I find an alternate method? Hoping there's some table (ew) hack or something that I havn't considered.

jsFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/JRz6a/1/

Image to demonstrate:

[image]

Comment: Are you setting `overflow:hidden` on the parent?

Comment: @jrod yes, updating with a jsFiddle to demonstrate

Comment: Looked at your fiddle and I see a clipped red box contained within the parent?  What browser are you using?

Comment: @jrod inspect the element- it's clipped, but not centered.

Answer (score 0):

you can try putting overflow:hidden in the parent.